# how to save and data to different Model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

you all,
I wanna try to implement saving data in another table.
There is favorite table and food table and what I need to do is to transfer to a food on favorite model to food table when users click add button.  When transferring I don't want lose the adding data from the favorite table, instead keeping it in the favorite table.

Any comment is helpful and thanks for your time in advance!!

```
def add_to_today_foods(request, pk):
  favorite = get_object_or_404(Favorite, pk=pk)
  food = favorite
  if request.method == 'POST':
      food.user = request.user
      food.save()
      return redirect('today_foods')
  context = {
    'food': food,
    'favorite': favorite,
  }
  return render(request, 'base/add_to_today_foods.html', context)
```

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import FoodCreate, FoodUpdate, FoodDelete, FoodList, TargetCreate

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.foods, name='today_foods'),
  path('all_foods', FoodList.as_view(), name='all_foods'),
  path('all_foods/search/', views.food_search, name='food_search'),
  path('favorite', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
  path('favorite/delete/<int:pk>', views.favorite_delete, name='favorite_delete'),
  path('favorite/update/<int:pk>', views.favorite_update, name='favorite_update'),
  path('favorite/add_to_today_foods/<int:pk>', views.add_to_today_foods, name='add_to_today_foods'),
  path('target', TargetCreate.as_view(), name='target'),
  # path('', FoodList.as_view(), name='foods'),
  path('create/', FoodCreate.as_view(), name='food-create'),
  path('update/<int:pk>', FoodUpdate.as_view(), name='food-update'),
  path('delete/<int:pk>', FoodDelete.as_view(), name='food-delete'),

]
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}｜お気に入り登録{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


<div class="header-bar">
  <a href="{% url 'today_foods' %}">&#8592; 戻る</a>
</div>

<div class="body-container">
  <div class="body-header">
    <h1>お気に入り登録</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="notion2">
    <p>※数字は半角で打ち込んでください</p>
  </div>
  <form action="{% url 'favorite' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button class="button" type="submit">追加</button>
  </form>

  <!-- table -->
  <div class="food-items-wrapper">
    <table>
      <tr class="table-header">
        <th class="align-left">食べもの</th>
        <th>kcal</th>
        <th>P</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>カテゴリ</th>
      </tr>
      {% if favorites %}
        {% for favorite in favorites %}
          <tr>
            <td class="align-left">{{ favorite.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ favorite.kcal }}</td>
            <td>{{ favorite.protein }}</td>
            <td>{{ favorite.fat }}</td>
            <td>{{ favorite.carb }}</td>
            <td>{{ favorite.category }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'favorite_update' favorite.id %}"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'favorite_delete' favorite.id %}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'add_to_today_foods' favorite.id %}"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
    {% else %}
      <td colspan="8" class="no-results">｜お気に入り登録された食べものはありません。｜</td>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from datetime import date
# Create your models here.
FOOD_CATEGORY = (('朝食','朝食'),('昼食','昼食'), ('夕食','夕食'),('間食','間食'))
class Food(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ユーザー')
  category = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=FOOD_CATEGORY, verbose_name='カテゴリー')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='名前')
  kcal = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='カロリー')
  protein = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True, default=0.0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999.9), MinValueValidator(0.0)], verbose_name='タンパク質')
  fat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True, default=0.0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999.9), MinValueValidator(0.0)], verbose_name='脂質')
  carb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True, default=0.0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999.9), MinValueValidator(0.0)], verbose_name='炭水化物')
  eaten_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='食べた日付', default=date.today, help_text='※yyyy-mm-dd')
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='作成日')
  def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Target(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ユーザー')
  kcal = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='カロリー')
  protein = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, default=0.0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999.9), MinValueValidator(0.0)], verbose_name='タンパク質')
  fat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, default=0.0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999.9), MinValueValidator(0.0)], verbose_name='脂質')
  carb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, default=0.0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999.9), MinValueValidator(0.0)], verbose_name='炭水化物')
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='作成日')
  # 以下はadminページでの表示、正味いらん、あとエラーになる
  # def __str__(self):
  #   return self.user

class Favorite(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ユーザー')
  category = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=FOOD_CATEGORY, verbose_name='カテゴリー')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='名前')
  kcal = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='カロリー')
  protein = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True, default=0.0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999.9), MinValueValidator(0.0)], verbose_name='タンパク質')
  fat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True, default=0.0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999.9), MinValueValidator(0.0)], verbose_name='脂質')
  carb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True, default=0.0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999.9), MinValueValidator(0.0)], verbose_name='炭水化物')
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='作成日')
  def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

Comment: Please provide the code for your models.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to put it. Now it's right there.

Answer (score 1):

You can read data from the food table, and create an object with these same values in the favourite foods table.
I can't see the models, so I can't provide the code you need to write.

As an alternative, you can also create a boolean field called favourite, to mark some food as favourite. This way you won't have to create a new model.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanna try to implement saving data in another table. There is favorite table and food table and what I need to do is to transfer to a food on favorite model to food table

Simple example how to copy data between two same tables:

MODEL example →

```py
from django.db import models

class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "food"

class Favorite(Food):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "favorite"
```

Copy process (copy food object with `ID = 1` into Favorites) →

```py
from djangoapp.models import Food, Favorite

food = Food.objects.get(id=1)
favorite = Favorite()
for attr in food._meta.fields:
  if attr.verbose_name == 'ID':
    continue
  setattr(favorite, attr.verbose_name, getattr(food, attr.verbose_name))
favorite.save()
```

**BUT! That is very bad way to duplicate data in DB without special reasons.**

For example, your food may be discontinued in menu but customer still will be able to see it in favorite data. So you need to delete data both food and favorite tables

Instead copy data the better way is to create relation table:

```py
from django.db import models

class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "food"

class Client(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "client"

class Favorite(models.Model):

    client_id = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    food_id = models.ForeignKey(Food)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "favorite"
```

After that you can add new record in favorites:

```py
favorite = Favorite()
favorite.client_id = 1
favorite.food_id = 2
favorite.save()
```

That means `Client` with `ID = 1` added `Food` with `ID = 2` to own `Favorites`

In this case if you remove `Food` with `ID = 2` favorites relation `[1,2]` also will be removed (depends on settings).

- EDIT 1 → update answer according additional model information

Ok, in your case copying food data into favorite will be something like

```
def add_to_today_foods(request, pk):
  food = get_object_or_404(Food, pk=pk)
  favorite = Favorite()
  
  if request.method == 'POST':
    for attr in food._meta.fields:
      if attr.verbose_name in ['ID', 'eaten_date']:
        continue
      setattr(favorite, attr.verbose_name, getattr(food, attr.verbose_name))
    favorite.user = request.user
    favorite.save()
    return redirect('today_foods')
  context = {
    'food': food,
    'favorite': favorite,
  }
  return render(request, 'base/add_to_today_foods.html', context)
```

＊しかし、データをコピーする方法、非常におすすめではりません。